# C# MySQL Select into Var -> Memory increasing

Tags: c#, mysql

I am new to C# and trying to read a value out of a MySQL Database.

What i get is a single number.
I store that into an int variable and check for specific numbers to activate functions of a kuando busylight.

The whole thing is looped (tried while (true) {} and goto methods).

It works so far, but my memory usage is increasing. starting at ~6 MiB...30MiB and so on.

Somehow it saves data into the process but I did not find out how  to clear the used memory.

As is said im very very new to this, maybe my code is toooooo crappy to work fine and its now problem of clearing unused data. just tell me :D

Thank you very much!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Plenom.Components.Busylight.Sdk;
using System.Threading;

namespace TANSS4BLL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
                var controller = new BusylightUcController();
                int resultStatus;
                while (true)
                {
                 string sqlDataBaseSelect = "SELECT typID FROM az_manager where maID = 4328 ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 1";
                 string ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; Database=tanss; Uid=root; Pwd=password"; 
                 using (MySqlConnection connDataBase = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                 {
                        connDataBase.Open();
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlDataBaseSelect, connDataBase);
                        resultStatus = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                        if (resultStatus == 1)
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine("Debugtext1");                              
                            controller.Light(BusylightColor.Green);

                        }
                        else if (resultStatus == 2)
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine("Debugtext2");

                            controller.Light(BusylightColor.Red);
                        }
                        else if (resultStatus == 3)
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine("Debugtext3");

                            controller.Light(BusylightColor.Red);
                        }
                        else if (resultStatus == 9)
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine("Debugtext4");

                            controller.Light(BusylightColor.Red);
                        }
                        connDataBase.Close();   
                }
                //Console.WriteLine(resultStatus);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                //Console.Clear();

             }
        }             
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide the class `BusylightUcController`? One thing tough: You don't have to recreate your db connection everytim ein the loop. Create and open it outside the loop. Also try to use timers instead of a while(true) loop

Comment: I would really like to! But i donw know how to do that. I just added the dll as reference out of the Busylight SDK Kit found on http://www.busylight.com/develop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating multiple connections to the database with your while(true) loop.

`string ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; Database=tanss; Uid=root; Pwd=password";`

This line can easily be move out of the while loop and you that should help with your problem.

Also, if this turns into production code, you need to set up parameters when you are working with the database.  Parameters are how we avoid sql injection.

[Avoiding SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163917.aspx)

Hopefully this helps you out!

Comment: And thats it! Clearly failed for the first time ;) Memory is now around 6MB even if running for a week :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to handle it, Garbage Collector will handle it automatically. But try to avoid reconnecting to database in loop. If you need to do it this way - put MySqlCommand in loop, not MySqlConnection.

Garbage Collector automaticaly clear unused resources. You can run Garbage collector manualy, but it is quite expensive operation, so don't put it inside while(true) loop. Mor info about GC is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5zscb2d(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I see that you are doing is you are not disposing of the MySqlCommand Object, that's going to continually build and take up resources.  You need to properly dispose of that object whether it be through a using statement or call the dispose method on it. Also I would start you mysql Connection outside the for loop if your going to continually poll the database.  I would also put some try catch logic into there as well to catch DB connection errors. Here is how I would attack this,

```
            var controller = new BusylightUcController();
            int resultStatus;
            string sqlDataBaseSelect = "SELECT typID FROM az_manager where maID = 4328 ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 1";
            string ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; Database=tanss; Uid=root; Pwd=password"; 
            using (MySqlConnection connDataBase = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                    connDataBase.Open();
                    try
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlDataBaseSelect, connDataBase))
                            {
                                resultStatus = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                                switch(resultStatus)
                                {
                                    case 1: 
                                        //Console.WriteLine("Debugtext1");                              
                                        controller.Light(BusylightColor.Green);
                                        break;
                                    case 2: 
                                        //Console.WriteLine("Debugtext2");
                                        controller.Light(BusylightColor.Red);
                                        break;
                                    case 3: 
                                        //Console.WriteLine("Debugtext3");
                                        controller.Light(BusylightColor.Red);
                                        break;
                                    case 9:
                                        //Console.WriteLine("Debugtext4");
                                        controller.Light(BusylightColor.Red);
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        // handle when its not any of your results.
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            //Console.WriteLine(resultStatus);
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            //Console.Clear();
                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        //HandleException
                    }finally
                    {
                        connDataBase.Close(); 
                    }    
            }
```

Comment: makes sense! i tried it but even if the connection is not made again in every loop, the memory usage increases like before!

Comment: Then its likely in your Controller Class, Is there something you are not disposing of or instantiating each time you call the Light Method?